# Value is not getting picked from application.yml file in test cases?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, resttemplate

I have defined a url in application.yml file as:

```
url:
  hosturl: http://someurl
```

And in my service class I am using @Value annotation like:

```
@Value("${url.hosturl}")
String url;
```

I am doing a rest call now which is working fine:

```
  ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

I have put a logger to see if it is getting url from it yml or not which seems to be working.

But in test cases it is still showing url as null and rest template is giving a null pointer exception.

```
*****urladd:****null/someEndpoint
```

Comment: can you show the whole class

Comment: try - application-test.yml  with activeProfile as test.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Did you add the source to the test? You should have something like `@TestPropertySource(locations = "/path_to_yml.yml")` in your test.